# gdx-pay: "package com.badlogic.gdx.pay does not exist"

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to implement gdx-pay in my libgdx project. So I followed the [Integration example with resolvers](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay/wiki/Integration-example-with-resolvers) from the libgdx wiki.

I have created a class `PlatformResolver` in my core project and a class `AndroidResolver` in my android project (as in the wiki). Both classes import `com.badlogic.gdx.pay.PurchaseManagerConfig`, but for my `AndroidResolver` I get a compiler error:

```
Error:(6, 28) error: package com.badlogic.gdx.pay does not exist
```

I have imported the `gdx-pay-0.4.0-library.jar` (which includes `com.badlogic.gdx.pay.PurchaseManagerConfig`) to my core project and     `gdx-pay-android-openiab-0.4.0-library.jar`, `gdx-pay-android-0.4.0-library.jar`, `gdx-pay-android-ouya-0.4.0-library.jar` to my android project.

As the android project also compiles the core project, `PurchaseManagerConfig` should be available to the android project, too, shouldn't it?

```
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        // ...
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

EDIT:

When I add `gdx-pay-0.4.0-library.jar` additionally to the android project (folder android/lib), everything compiles fine (still no idea why it's neccessary). But then I could never restore or buy items because of

```
I/ERROR﹕ gdx-pay: requestPurchaseRestore(): purchaseManager == null
```

But this seems to be a ProGuard problem. Without ProGuard I get:

```
I/IAP﹕ IAP: gdx-pay successfully instantiated.
I/﹕ gdx-pay: installed manager: OpenIAB/null
```

Although my project compiles now, I nevertheless would be glad if somebody could explain me why I have to add the jar file twice because that could help me understand some other gradle issues.

Comment: Sounds like you were not successful in correctly importing the core pay library to your core project. So whatever copy of it you think you put in core is being completely ignored. Probably has to do with the path you defined in `build.gradle` not matching up with where you put it. The Proguard issue can be solved with the proguard config file. Look up what lines need to be added for gdx-pay. The library might be doing something with reflection.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! With the latest ProGuard file from the wiki it seems to work. The `gdx-pay-0.4.0-library.jar` is located in `core/libs` and in `build.gradle` I use the same line for the core and the android project: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`

Comment: Seems like that should work. I'm not sure why it's not loading the one in your core directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

In build.gradle:

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    ***
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-android:0.9.2"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-android-openiab:0.9.2:library"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-android-ouya:0.9.2:library"
}
```

}